# Authenticating Google App Script with Bearer token

Tags: javascript, ios, google-apps-script, google-oauth

### Take the following scenario

1. Google Sign In set up on iOS Client
2. Obtain accessToken for Forms and Drive (same that the App Script will use in next steps)
3. Write the following simple app script to return some detail about a Form

```js
function doGet(request) {
  if (request.parameter.formId !== undefined) {
    const formId = String(request.parameter.formId);
    const form = FormApp.openById(formId);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
      'status': 'success',
      "message": form.isAcceptingResponses()
    }));
  }
}
```

4. Expose this app script as a web app with its given Public URL; set settings to Execute by Anyone and as the Current User
5. Call this end point with an `Authorization: Bearer ***` header from iOS Client (passing the token obtained by native OAuth flow (valid/non-expired token)

### What Is Happening / Issue

The above described scenario works as expected for the Google Account that owns the App Script Project (both in browser with direct url navigation and REST call). This also works as expected for all other Google Accounts when navigating to the app script url .in the browser.

However, for Google Accounts other than mine that owns the Project, the App Script fails over REST. The response is a HTML page dump. If proper bearer token is NOT provided, the html response is clearly shown as Unauthorized. When token is provided, a varying html page is in the response.

### Notes

After a long scavenger hunt, I can confirm the following

- `appscript.json` manifest has appropriate oauthScopes
- The requesting client oauth token matches these scopes
- There is a single Google Cloud Project with the Drive and Forms APIs enabled
- Tried hitting th `/dev` variant fo the URL in case the page returned is the insecure client page that Google shows for apps that have not gone through scope verification yet.

Deployment Set To:

[image]

---

A bit stumped as to what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Happy to share any additional context I may have missed.

Could it be the fact that the Project is not verified by Google yet? I would still imagine that I should be able to hit the web app url with a few different accounts to test?

Comment: About `set settings to Execute by Anyone and as the Current User`, what values of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:`? And, I cannot understand the relationship between `This also works as expected for all other Google Accounts when navigating to the app script url .in the browser.` and `However, for Google Accounts other than mine that owns the Project, the App Script fails over REST.`. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: By the way, although I'm not sure about your actual situation, when you share the Google Apps Script project including your showing script with the users you want to test and test it again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike Execute as is set to `User Accessing the Web App` and Who Has Access to `Anyone With Google Account`.

```This also works as expected for all other Google Accounts when navigating to the app script url .in the browser.```

What I mean is that when I go to the web app url for another Google User (logged into browser), the App Script executes correctly and returns appropriate json. When I can same url via Postman with Bearer token authorization, I don't get that same response. Hopefully that clarifies it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, your Web Apps is deployed as `Execute as: User Accessing the Web App` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone With Google Account`. In this case, when the Web Apps is accessed with the browser logged by the user, the Web Apps can be accessed. But, in order to access with the HTTP request to Web Apps using a script, it is required to share your Google Apps Script project with the users. Please share it with the users and test it again.